# Spring Boot How to define @Components in src/test so they can @Autowire into tests?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to do integration tests of REST api.  I've written some testing utility classes to build test data, and I'd like to `@Autowire` them into my test methods.  When running my tests, the `@Autowire` fails as Spring doesn't know about these components.  I started down the path of adding inner `@Configuration` class to my tests, but I am trying to `@Autowire` repositories into these utilities, so I need that `@Autowire` chain to work.  Can this be done?  How do I do it?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-it.properties")
public class ContactControllerIT
{
    @Autowired
    private ContactController contactController;   // <---  This autowires as expected

    @Autowired
    private TestContactBuilder contactBuilder;    // <--- This class is defined in src/test and autowired fail w/ no bean found error
```

Example Project: https://github.com/tbbstny/spring-boot-it-study

Comment: I think you can just autowire the component under src/main. and it a bad idea to have a component under src/test
Can you show us the code of TestContactBuilder.java and also your contactController

Comment: That should just work (as long as the packages are covered by component scanning from Spring Boot). Also I assume the sources are in `src/test/java` and not `src/test`.

Comment: Yes, they are in src/test/java.  I've added a link to an example project in github.

Why is it a bad idea to have @Components in test code?  The component is for testing use only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the Controller you dont need to use it in your Tests. You'd use MockMvc

Here is Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SomeTest {

 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Test
 public void getGeneratedPassword_shouldReturn200Status() throws Exception {
 boolean isGenerated = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/generate/password/1").with(httpBasic(this.username, this.password)))
        .andExpect(authenticated())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn()
        .getResponse()
        .getContentAsString().isEmpty;

 assertFalse(isGenerated);
  }    
}
```

Test going to pass since it will return not Empty String. There is also 2 Stages of Validation. If user is Correct and if HTTP Status 200.

Its going to work with 2.1.0 Spring Boot and higher. You can also add your application.properties path.

Documentation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

The other which can be used in your current code is to add this Annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ContactController.class, TestContactBuilder.class})
```

Comment: I should have added more code.  I've updated the question to include a link to an example project on github.

I only include a controller so I can do this: `mvc = standaloneSetup(contactController).build();`in a `@Before` method.

Answer (score 0):

Determined this was not an issue of getting src/test/java to be scanned, but rather an understanding with Spring Boot's default scanning process. I added my data builder components to a different package than then one annotated with @SpringBootApplication. By default, Spring will do component scanning of that package and anything nested in that package only. There are two ways then to fix my issue:

1. Move the data building utils into/under the same package as `@SpringBootApplication` i.e. com.ttt.example.api
2. Add `@ComponentScan`
   to the Application class to include the package the data builder
   utils are in.

   ```
   @ComponentScan("com.ttt.example")  // <-- Move up to root package to ensure all my components are scanned
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application
   ```